View which were the nearest neighbors in tidymodel workflow
I have a similar question like this: How to view the nearest neighbors in R?
Code example:
library(tidymodels)

knn_rec <- recipe(Species ~ ., data = iris)

knn_lookup <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(nearest_neighbor(neighbors = 3) %>%
    set_engine("kknn") %>% 
    set_mode("classification")) %>%
  add_recipe(knn_rec) %>%
  fit(data = iris)

knn_pred <- predict(knn_lookup , new_data = iris[1,1:4], type = "raw")

How can I trace back which rows were identified as the 3 nearest neighbors? I'd prefer something simple like tidy() within the tidyverse.

The kknn package does all of the work for you. If you use any steps with the recipe, make sure that you prep and bake the data to get the real values used by the models.
Here's a simple example:
library(tidymodels)
library(kknn)

data(two_class_dat)

set.seed(1)
dat_split <- initial_split(two_class_dat)
dat_train <- training(dat_split)
dat_test  <- testing(dat_split)

knn_obj <- 
  kknn(
    Class ~ .,
    dat_train,
    dat_test %>% select(-Class) %>% head(),
    k = 3,
    kernel = "triangular"
  )

# Indicies of neighbors
knn_obj$C
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   72  247  152
#> [2,]  336  397  113
#> [3,]   13  528  329
#> [4,]  218  362  298
#> [5,]  566  258  392
#> [6,]  579   66  302

# Weights: 
knn_obj$W
#>           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,] 0.3461305 0.2225861 0.08587877
#> [2,] 0.2912265 0.2832970 0.15322362
#> [3,] 0.8111406 0.4207619 0.26617555
#> [4,] 0.8868195 0.4606245 0.21953733
#> [5,] 0.5464303 0.3773175 0.32209628
#> [6,] 0.7769446 0.7006026 0.12411210

Created on 2024-11-11 with reprex v2.1.1

In your question, you mentioned using tidy() which its from broom package, yes, is useful for summarizing the results of model, It's a less complex way to work with tidyverse.
Using kknn, You have to fit the model into your training data:
for example:
knn_fit <- fit(knn_spec, mpg ~ ., data = train_data)

now extract the nearest neighbors for a specific observation, use the kknn::kknn() function directly.
for a new observation do:
#example
new_observation <- data.frame(cyl = 6, disp = 160, hp = 110, drat = 3.9, wt = 2.62, qsec = 16.46, vs = 0, am = 1, gear = 4, carb = 4)

neighbors <- kknn::kknn(mpg ~ ., train_data, new_observation, k = 5, distance = 2)  # i used minkowski distances
print(neighbors)

an output would show you the nearest neighbors along with their predicted values.
kknn has their own documentation if necessary.

The only thing I get with print is the model specs "Call: kknn:kknn..."?
